# Can you make 4 bars with 4 columns of data using matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I need to make a bar graph where x-axis plot the index `([1992,1993,1994,1995])` and y-axis will plot 4 columns of random data as shown below. It will generate 4 bars for 4 columns of data. How can I do that? I am pretty new to matplotlib. Please help. This is the DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650),np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

df.head()
```

Comment: Is that bar plot ? I feel like you may need `violinplot` https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html

Comment: Yes, this should be a bar plot

Comment: Your dataframe has 3650 columns and four rows. Try ```df.transpose()```

Comment: A bar plot with four bars would show a total of 4 values; you have 4*3650 values. Can you clarify what you're looking for? Perhaps a scatterplot where each point is shown?